# mod24_ssl won't read certificate that validates against openssl

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-ec2

So I'm having issues trying to start apache on an EC2 server.

Specs:

```
OS: Amazon Linux AMI r2016.03
httpd24.x86_  64 2.4.18-1.64.amzn1
mod24_ssl.x86_64 2.4.18-1.64.amzn1
```

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot            /var/www/zxurian.com/html/
    ServerAdmin             root@localhost.com
    ServerName              zxurian.com

    DirectoryIndex          index.php

    SSLEngine               on
    SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1
    SSLCipherSuite          "AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH"
    SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/httpd/ssl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/certificate.cc-bundle
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/httpd/ssl/certificate.key

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

    <Directory "/var/www/zxurian.com">
            Require all granted
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch "^\.">
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from All
    </FilesMatch>
    <DirectoryMatch "^\.|\/\.">
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from All
    </DirectoryMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

I copied a private key & the purchased certificate to the server to use. Running `openssl x509 -noout -text -in certificate.crt` shows me the certificate information. Running `openssl rsa -in certificate.key -check` gives me a `RSA key ok`. However when trying to start apache, I get the following error:

```
[Tue May 17 21:07:12.592129 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 8896] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for hub.tantor.com:443
[Tue May 17 21:07:12.592145 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 8896] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: DH PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Tue May 17 21:07:12.592151 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 8896] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: EC PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Tue May 17 21:07:12.592158 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 8896] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
```

At this point, I'm out of ideas. I've verified that the file has no extra line endings. `vi -b` on the files shows no extra information in the files (ie, no `^M` or windows line endings). It's setup identical to my other working fine EC2 servers.

Anyone have anything else I can check?

Added per request:

```
[zxurian@ip-10-0-200-22 ssl]$ egrep 'BEGIN|END' certificate.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
[zxurian@ip-10-0-200-22 ssl]$ egrep 'BEGIN|END' certificate.key
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: It's probably no consolation, but I suspect the error messages are lying about the real problem.  You might edit the post to include the output of `egrep 'BEGIN|END' /etc/httpd/ssl/certificate.crt` and the same thing for the other files, for a sanity check.

Comment: added to original post

Comment: I apologize in advance if I'm sending you down a black hole, as I try to avoid apache whenever possible... but shouldn't that private key say `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`?  Convert it: `openssl rsa -in certificate,key -out certificate.rsakey` then change your config to use the newly created file.

Comment: the keyfile I have on another EC2 server (identical Amazon Linux/Apache/mod24_ssl setup) also has `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`, but for the sake of argument I tried to converted the key to rsa, switched keyfile in apache config, still same error.

Answer (score 2):

First the clue: You can't rely on just your `VirtualHost` definition anymore. You *must* reference a valid certificate/key pair from conf.d/ssl.conf like so (locations are for my Fedora system):

> SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
>
> SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.pem

Mine is a self-signed cert, carried over from httpd-2.2/openssl-1.0.2h. The cert is in ascii PEM format. The key was converted to an RSA clear copy, so no password is required when httpd starts. (carefully evaluate your environment before you do that). It doesn't matter much what the cert is made for it seems, because it is still the certs, defined in the VirtualHost section that will be presented to the clients. For me those certs (carried over from httpd-2.2) are in PEM short form, while the respective keys, again are in RSA clear copy form. Of course you must have mod_ssl.so loaded, but if you had things working in httpd-2.2 then you already did that. For the record: There isn't a dhparams.pem file anywhere on my system (just another false lead in my case).